# What is the best way to fallback to the html5 input widgets on mobile, and using widget libs on desktops?

Tags: django, html, angularjs

I have a application written in Django and my front-end uses AngularJS.

I'm making the application responsive; but I have some input widgets that don't play well on mobile screens (ex: datepicker, numberpicker, etc).
I want to disable these widgets on the mobile browsers, but I don't know the best way to do it.

For example, bootstrap datepicker is used as a embeddable component (as a `div`), but to transform it into a html5 input, I must replace it with a `input type="text"` and don't initialize the datepicker.

Should I make this change on my datepicker directive, or in the django template, returning the div or the input based on the browser?

Comment: Use an `<input type="date">`; detect screen size/touch support/whatever is relevant. If Bootstrap’s date picker can’t handle that… that’s its failing. Whatever you do, though, *don’t* do browser sniffing, and don’t do it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech.

I would change the template to use the standard html elements, like `<input type="date">`, then use javascript to detect the device size and replace the code on desktop sizes only (until about 767px).

My advice for this procedure is that (usually) desktop browsers are much more powerful and faster at processing and coping with DOM transformations in real time. If that happens in a mobile device, it will be slower or more prone to errors/bugs. On desktops these DOM changes are nearly imperceptible.

As an alternative with less javascript, you can double all elements, using both standard and non-standard pairs. Then, add a class like `.mobile` to the standard ones, and `.desktop` to the others. Finally, on the css styles, use:

```
.mobile {display: none;} //all styles

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .mobile {display: block;}
    .desktop {display: none;}
}
```

I also think this question is a good example of how standard html becomes more scalable for other devices.

Hope it helps.